# Error Attempt to de-reference null object to some users

Tags: apex, soql

I need to update a field in case with appropriate conditions based on  subscription object relationship with account and update related case. But it throws error sometimes.

> Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.ARPUCases.RevenueLoss:
>   line 179, column 1 Trigger.ForARPU: line 11, column 1
>
> **line 179, column 1** Would be below

```
if(a.Revenue_Since__c <> null && cs.Contract_Term__c <> null) 
                {
                    RevenueContract=cs.Revenue_effective__c.daysBetween(a.Revenue_Since__c.addMonths((Integer)cs.Contract_Term__c));
                    System.debug('DATA in RevenueContract Calculation '+ RevenueContract);
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in the account '+ a.Revenue_Since__c);
                }
```

My Apex Class

```
public static void RevenueLoss(List<Case> CaseTriggers) 
    {
        Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order'].Id;
        List<Case> CaseIDs = new List<Case>();
        system.debug('Old Values'+CaseTriggers);
        Set<Id> CaseAccountIds = new set<Id>();
        for (Case s : CaseTriggers)
        {
            if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && s.Case_Details__c =='Cancell' && s.Revenue_effective__c <> null) 
            {
                // Loop through and add caseId's to the list.
                CaseIDs.add(s);
                // Loop through and add AccountId to the accountId Set
                CaseAccountIds.add(s.AccountId);
            }
            if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && s.Case_Details__c =='Cancell' && s.Revenue_effective__c == null && s.Revenue_Loss__c <> null) 
            {
                s.Revenue_Loss__c=null;
            }
        }

        Map<Id,Account> accountInfoMap=new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Revenue_Since__c from account where Id=:CaseAccountIds]);
        Integer DaysDifference=0,RevenueContract=0;
        Map<Id,Zuora__Subscription__c> subscriptionByAccountMap= new Map<Id,Zuora__Subscription__c>();

        for(Zuora__Subscription__c subscription:[SELECT Id,Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c,Zuora__Account__c FROM Zuora__Subscription__c WHERE Zuora__Account__c = :CaseAccountIds ORDER BY CreatedDate]){
            subscriptionByAccountMap.put(subscription.Zuora__Account__c,subscription);
        }

        for(Case cs:CaseIDs) 
        {
            System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
            Account a = accountInfoMap.get(cs.AccountId);
            Zuora__Subscription__c sub = subscriptionByAccountMap.get(cs.AccountId);

            if(a!=null && sub!=null){
                //update case only if it is associated to an Account and a Subscription
                if(sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c <> null && cs.Revenue_effective__c <> null ) 
                {
                    DaysDifference=cs.Revenue_effective__c.daysBetween(sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c Before '+ sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in DaysDifference Calculation '+ DaysDifference);
                }
            }
                if(a.Revenue_Since__c <> null && cs.Contract_Term__c <> null) 
                {
                    RevenueContract=cs.Revenue_effective__c.daysBetween(a.Revenue_Since__c.addMonths((Integer)cs.Contract_Term__c));
                    System.debug('DATA in RevenueContract Calculation '+ RevenueContract);
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in the account '+ a.Revenue_Since__c);
                }
                if(DaysDifference>=RevenueContract) 
                {
                    cs.Revenue_Loss__c = (cs.Total_units_ordered__c)*DaysDifference*(cs.ARPU__c/31);
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_Loss__c Days Difference Calculation '+ cs.Revenue_Loss__c);
                }
                else if(RevenueContract>DaysDifference) 
                {
                    cs.Revenue_Loss__c = (cs.Total_units_ordered__c)*RevenueContract*(cs.ARPU__c/31);
                }


        }

    }
```

But why is there an error sometimes, then when I try to create case with seemingly same data everything is working fine?

I logged in as the user experiencing issues and I am able to create a case. But the user had been unable to create a case with the same information.

Comment: 1) can you not debug each value before it enters your IF to see where the null is? 2) if there are too many values for logs, why not spit out everything into an attached .csv, open it, and check for "null"?

Comment: Will you more specific i am not able to understand @Grant

Answer (score 1):

if this value is null `cs.Revenue_effective__c` you will get an exception. So add this in your if condition.

```
if(a.Revenue_Since__c <> null && cs.Contract_Term__c <> null && cs.Revenue_effective__c <> null)
```

Comment: But in case level cs.Revenue_effective__c field having data but it also throwing error to the user @Tushar Sharma

Comment: @Pavantej may be your user don't have access to that field.

Comment: Actually User have access to Revenue_Since__c,Contract_Term__c as well as Revenue_effective__c in case well. @Tushar Sharma

Comment: @Pavantej in this case use system.debug to printe there value there might be some records in which this value is blank. Best is put a null check.